# How does Parallels' CPU and ram usage work? When to shutdown virtual machine?

Tags: windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop, cpu

I run Windows 7 using Parallels in host operating system OSX.
I have it configured to use 2GM ram and 2 cores on a Retina MacBook Pro with 8GB ram.

I'm curious under what conditions I will experience a performance hit either in terms of CPU usage. Ultimately, I'm interested in whether it is best when Windows 7 in parallels is not in active use, to:

(a) suspend Windows 7 in Parallels 
(b) shut down Windows 7 in Parallels
(c) Quit parallels completely

#### Initial observations

Using the activity monitor, I noticed the following:

- When idle the Windows 7 virtual machine `prl_vm_app` was using around 2GB of ram and 2 to 2.5% of CPU
- When Windows 7 was suspended or turned off the process disappeared completely

In addition, when Parallels was running with a virtual machine runnning or not, it used around 200 MB and about 0.5% of cpu.

So my initial conclusion is that if you are short on ram, then suspending or shutting down the virtual OS is a good idea. There is also some small background CPU usage if you don't shut it down. 
However, I'm worried that I'm missing something.

#### Questions

- Does running a virtual machine running in Parallels on OSX use additional CPU or other resources over and beyond the CPU usage indicated in Activity Monitor? For example does it reserve cores?
- Are there any good rules of thumb about whether or when to suspend the virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, let's see what we can do here!

---

## 1) Suspending vs. Shutting Down in Parallels

### a) How it affects the host OS

Both options do not affect the host operating system - in your case, OS X - from a resource usage standpoint. Rather, they only affect how the guest OS will boot next time - (i.e. waking up from sleep vs. a cold boot).

When suspending, it works just like a physical Windows machine: it saves the current state of the operating system for later use. Unlike a physical machine, however, it uses no extra battery power, RAM, or CPU cycles to do so; Parallels unloads it from RAM and stores it purely on the hard disk (think of it closer to a Windows laptop "hibernating" than "sleeping").

### b) How it affects the guest OS

On the other hand, both of these options have a more prominent effect on the guest OS. Aside from the standard reasons one might want to shut down a computer versus letting it sleep (updates, troubleshooting, etc.), there's one other reason to shut down the virtual machine: Parallels locks down quite a few of the guest OS settings (boot order, coherence mode, shared apps, etc.) and prevents them from being changed if the virtual machine state is anything other than shut down.

### c) Which should be used?

In my personal experience with Parallels, I have found no issues with using sleep consistently between sessions. The only time I shut down virtual machines is if I want to change some of the Parallels settings for that particular guest OS or if I encounter an odd bug that can pop up in Windows from time to time.

## 2) Resource Usage

### a) RAM

A set amount of RAM is reserved specifically for the guest OS - which you indicated to be 2GB; Parallels will not use significantly more or less.

### b) CPU

#### i) Usage

CPU, like the guest OS hard disk, is used on an "as-needed" basis and is accurately reported in the Activity Monitor.

#### ii) Reservation or parking

Parallels will not reserve (or "park") cores; the option you see in the guest OS options (Hardware > CPU & Memory > CPUs) merely limits the number cores that the guest OS will **have access to** rather than purely **reserving** them exclusively. This way the guest OS can extensively use these assigned cores, and if the guest OS begins to have a large work load, the host OS can use the remaining cores to continue its business without having processes choked from the guest OS.

---

Hopefully that helps you out! If you have any questions or need clarification on any of that, comment and let me know!

Comment: Also I just realized this question is more than a year old. Whoops!